# Why my script doesn't work, I think all done well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why my script doesn't work. I copied the code from [jsfiddle.com](http://jsfiddle.net/kXmpY/1/), there it works, but in my browser not. What the reasons can be ?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>JavaScript test</title>
  <script>
  document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate;
  var i = 0;
  var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');
  function duplicate() {
      var clone = original.cloneNode(true); 
      clone.id = "duplicetor" + ++i; 
      original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="button" onlick="duplicate()">Click me</button>
  <div id="duplicater">
      duplicate EVERYTHING INSIDE THIS DIV
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The script runs at it's place in the code - at that time, the html does not yet exist.  In jsfiddle, it's (by default) set to run when the page has finished loading.  Add an onload or document.ready to run your script when the page is ready.

Comment: The button handler is on the “onlick” attribute...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is your javascript function is loaded inside head which gets called before the element is generated. Add the following code,

```
 window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate;
  var i = 0;
  var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');
  function duplicate() {
      var clone = original.cloneNode(true); 
      clone.id = "duplicetor" + ++i; 
      original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
  }
  });
```

**DEMO**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>JavaScript test</title>
  <script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate;
  var i = 0;
  var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');
  function duplicate() {
      var clone = original.cloneNode(true); 
      clone.id = "duplicetor" + ++i; 
      original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
  }
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="button" onlick="duplicate()">Click me</button>
  <div id="duplicater">
      duplicate EVERYTHING INSIDE THIS DIV
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The script tag must be written at the end of the page .

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>JavaScript test</title>
  <script>

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="button" onlick="duplicate()">Click me</button>
  <div id="duplicater">
      duplicate EVERYTHING INSIDE THIS DIV
  </div>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate;
  var i = 0;
  var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');
  function duplicate() {
      var clone = original.cloneNode(true); 
      clone.id = "duplicetor" + ++i; 
      original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you're hoisting and setting an event listener before the dom element is read in the document (document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate;). Doing this throws an error. If you run your script and hoist after the element you're trying to manipulate is read, it seems to work.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>JavaScript test</title>
  <script>

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="button" onlick="duplicate()">Click me</button>
  <div id="duplicater">
      duplicate EVERYTHING INSIDE THIS DIV
  </div>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate;
  var i = 0;
  var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');
  function duplicate() {
      var clone = original.cloneNode(true); 
      clone.id = "duplicetor" + ++i; 
      original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialized first the element before calling it on your javascript function. So just transfer your javascript before your  tag.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>JavaScript test</title>

</head>
<body>
  <button id="button" onlick="duplicate()">Click me</button>
  <div id="duplicater">
      duplicate EVERYTHING INSIDE THIS DIV
  </div>
  <script>
  document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate;
  var i = 0;
  var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');
  function duplicate() {
      var clone = original.cloneNode(true); 
      clone.id = "duplicetor" + ++i; 
      original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your script in body section

```js
  document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate;
  var i = 0;
  var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');
  function duplicate() {
      var clone = original.cloneNode(true); 
      clone.id = "duplicetor" + ++i; 
      original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>JavaScript test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="button" onlick="duplicate()">Click me</button>
  <div id="duplicater">
      duplicate EVERYTHING INSIDE THIS DIV
  </div>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```